# How to recover and play this seemingly damaged file

Tags: video, data-recovery, vlc-media-player, video-conversion, video-encoding

I was recording a video with an Android mobile for a minute only to discover that the phone was off by the time I stopped recording. Why would it power off, I have no idea, for the battery was "blue" yet, not "orange" level. Anyway, VLC refuses to play the file. The tools to recover videos are quite expensive, and the most acclaimed tool Video Repair, only shows a preview of a few seconds, which s claimed to constitute 50% of the whole recovered video length. Thus, I conclude that it can only recover about 10 seconds of the minute-long video.

Here is the VLC log at verbosity level 2:

```
main debug: processing request item: VID_20170203_194303.mp4, node: Playlist, skip: 0
main debug: resyncing on VID_20170203_194303.mp4
main debug: VID_20170203_194303.mp4 is at 0
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on VID_20170203_194303.mp4
main debug: VID_20170203_194303.mp4 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'VID_20170203_194303.mp4'
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\X5650\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `file:///C:/Users/X5650/Documents/VID_20170203_194303.mp4' gives access `file' demux `' path `/C:/Users/X5650/Documents/VID_20170203_194303.mp4'
main debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='' location='/C:/Users/X5650/Documents/VID_20170203_194303.mp4' file='C:\Users\X5650\Documents\VID_20170203_194303.mp4'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 12 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access 'file' location='/C:/Users/X5650/Documents/VID_20170203_194303.mp4', path='C:\Users\X5650\Documents\VID_20170203_194303.mp4'
main debug: looking for access module matching "file": 20 candidates
filesystem debug: opening file `C:\Users\X5650\Documents\VID_20170203_194303.mp4'
main debug: using access module "filesystem"
main debug: Using stream method for AStream*
main debug: starting pre-buffering
main debug: received first data after 0 ms
main debug: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 1000000 KiB/s
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 6 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 6 candidates
main debug: using stream_filter module "record"
main debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='' location='/C:/Users/X5650/Documents/VID_20170203_194303.mp4' file='C:\Users\X5650\Documents\VID_20170203_194303.mp4'
main debug: looking for demux module matching "mp4": 63 candidates
mp4 debug: dumping root Box "root"
mp4 debug: | + ftyp size 24
mp4 debug: | + free size 405000
mp4 debug: | + mdat size 1061109567
mp4 debug: 3GPP Media file Release: 4
mp4 error: MP4 plugin discarded (no moov,foov,moof box)
es error: cannot peek
es error: cannot peek
es error: cannot peek
es error: cannot peek
es error: cannot peek
playlist debug: not enough data
playlist debug: not enough data
mod debug: MOD validation failed (ext=mp4)
ps error: cannot peek
mpgv error: cannot peek
mjpeg warning: no more data
mjpeg error: cannot peek
avcodec debug: trying url: C:\Users\X5650\Documents\VID_20170203_194303.mp4
avcodec warning: cannot peek
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\X5650\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\playlist
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\anevia_streams.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\anevia_xml.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\appletrailers.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\bbc_co_uk.luac
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\break.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\canalplus.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\cue.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\dailymotion.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\extreme.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\france2.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\googlevideo.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\jamendo.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\joox.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\katsomo.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\koreus.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\lelombrik.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\liveleak.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\metacafe.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\metachannels.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\mpora.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\pinkbike.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\pluzz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\rockbox_fm_presets.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\soundcloud.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\vimeo.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\youtube.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\youtube_homepage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\zapiks.luac
ps error: cannot peek
vobsub debug: could not read vobsub IDX file
main debug: no demux modules matched
main error: no suitable demux module for `file/:///C:/Users/X5650/Documents/VID_20170203_194303.mp4'
main debug: removing module "record"
main debug: removing module "filesystem"
main debug: finished input
main debug: dead input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is about *computer* hardware or software but: You cannot recover data that was never written. There are too many buffers in play to know when the data would be written and it sounds like you don't even have a clue if the whole length of time would have been recorded in the first place. "Blue" and "orange" are not particularly accurate battery levels, and could constitute anything from 5% to 100% battery. Recording video might have put just too much load on an almost completely drained battery causing the undervoltage cutout to trigger.

Comment: Recording with very low battery levels is a bad idea.  Firstly, writing to flash devices requires an order of magnitude more power than simply reading from them, and an order of magnitude more again if the flash cell being written to has to be erased first.  This means that recording a video can be a *very* heavy power drain in the phone, on top of that you will be using an extra piece of the phone you would not use during "normal" use: the video encoder block.  While this will be using dedicated hardware it will still be using more power than not recording video.

Comment: Secondly, batteries voltage is not a good indicator of capacity under a variable load and under heavy load it can dip incredibly quickly, yet this is what the battery indicator on your phone uses to show you.  Under "normal" load it is reasonably useful, but for heavy loads such as gaming or recording things it can be less than accurate for quite some time or will show a very sudden drop in life expectancy.

Comment: The curious part about it is that for the rest of the evening, with Wi-Fi on and two more half-a-minute-long videos recorded, the phone would never turn off again. Looks like I pressed something somewhere..